# How can I make my bread pudding firmer?

Tags: baking, bread-pudding

I have a bread pudding recipe I like, but would like to make it firmer.  How would I go about this ?

Comment: Can you provide the recipe that you're using?

Comment: What sort of bread pudding, there are a few types. That have completely different methods.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

- Use less custard
- Use more thickener (flour/cornstarch) in the custard
- Bake it longer on a lower heat to dry it out a little more

Comment: That last may put it at risk for making it rubbery if the eggs overcoagualate.  Would have to be watched carefully to ensure it doesn't get much above 180 F.

Comment: This might be a US/UK thing, but as far as I'm concerned, there is no custard in bread pudding. Bread-and-butter pudding is bread and butter soaked in custard and baked. Bread pudding is a dense cake of breadcrumbs, flour, spice, eggs and sugar. http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2011/dec/04/nigel-slater-classic-bread-pudding

Comment: Yup, I think your right @slim. To North American's bread pudding is bread that has been cut into chunks or torn apart and soaked in a custard and then baked in a casserole type dish. Kind of like rustic french toast or what you would call bread and butter pudding apparently.

Answer (score 3):

Use a firmer bread, or buy unsliced bread and cut thicker pieces.